# How to replace a single quote character with two single quote characters

Tags: postgresql, replace

I want to replace all instances of a string quote (`'`) with two single quotes (`''`) in a string.

Lets say `e'QmfgLu/]sf]/sd` is a string and I want to replace `'` with `''`.

The result must be  `e''OmfgLu/]`

I tried this query:

```
update customer set name=REGEXP_REPLACE(name, E'\'', '''');
```

also

```
 update customer set name=REPLACE(name, E'\'', '''');
```

This query is not properly working. What is the suitable way to write the query?

Comment: i want to replace ' with ''.eg. ra'm must be ra''m

Comment: What if the string already contains two single quotes, e.g. `foo''bar` - what is the expected result then? Four single quotes? `foo''''bar`

Comment: for me if foo''bar the result must be same ie.foo''bar. if there is only single ' then it must me replaced by ''. how can  i get the result as you suggested foo''''bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may replace a single occurrence of single quotes with 2 quotes using this regexp.

```
update customer set name=REGEXP_REPLACE(name, $$([^'])'([^'])$$, $$\1''\2$$ ,'g');
```

`$$([^'])'([^'])$$` - represents a sequence of any character other than a single quote followed by a quote and then a  non-quote character.

I'm using the [dollar quoting](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/376-Dollar-quoting-for-escaping-single-quotes.html) to avoid confusing quotes.

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=05cbdde5ff8159513f0ebad592e8abeb)

**EDIT**

As @edruid pointed out, to handle case for quotes at the start and end of string, use:
 `REGEXP_REPLACE(name, $$([^']|^)'(?!')$$, $$\1''$$ ,'g')`

This uses a [**`negative lookahead`**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for matching a single quote - `(?!')`

[**Demo2**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=dbcd8793eee6f7084d620b0b019b33e8)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This gave me the output what i wanted

Comment: This does not function as expected when the single quote is at the start or end of the string (as [^'] matches a character that is not ' (but still something)). `REGEXP_REPLACE(name, $$([^']|^)'(?!')$$, $$\1''$$ ,'g');` should work

Answer (score 3):

In postgres the way to have a single quote in a string is to type '' (' is used as the escape character) so your replace would be

```
update customer set name=REGEXP_REPLACE(name, E'''', '''''', 'g');
```

(skip the final 'g' if you only want to replace the first ')

or without resorting to regexp:

```
update customer set name=REPLACE(name, '''', '''''');
```